# Particular overload of Azure Mobile Service invokeApi is not working while calling custom API

Tags: android, azure, mobile, service, sdk

Where is the documentation/sample for all overloads of invokeApi function for Azure Mobile Service client SDK for Android?

I found [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/futures-support-and-breaking-changes-in-azure-mobile-services-android-sdk/) article and tried following code, which does not work. There are no compile time or run time errors, invokeApi gets called, but it does not come back to onSuccess or onFailure. If I call invokeApi without order object, everything works as expected

```
            PizzaOrder order = new PizzaOrder();
            order.Size = "Large";
            order.Flavor = "Four cheeses";
            order.UserPhone = "555-555-1234";

            ListenableFuture<PizzaOrderResponse> testresult = mClient.invokeApi("bookservice", order, PizzaOrderResponse.class);

            Futures.addCallback(testresult, new FutureCallback<PizzaOrderResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable exc) {
                  // failure handling code here
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PizzaOrderResponse testresult) {
                  // success handling code here
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the properties in the data object being returned by the custom API had incorrect data type. I am still not sure where the good documentation is and why custom API call did not fail but at least it is working now.